# How to display Logs of Django middleware in terminal

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

I created my own Middleware to validate HTTP-Requests. To make sure everything works fine, I added some logs into the code. I excpect that they will be display in the terminal (if reached obviously).

```
import logging

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class ValidationMiddleware:

    # init-Method is called once the server starts
    
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    # call-Method is called for every new request to the Django application
    
    def __call__(self, request):

        # Code to be executed before middleware is called
        validate_settings = settings.VALIDATIONMIDDLEWARE.get("default")

        token_header = 'X-Token'

        if token_header in request.headers:
            request_token = request.headers[token_header]
            url = validate_settings.get("VALIDATE_URL")
            md5_token = hashlib.md5(request_token.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
            payload = {'checksum': md5_token}
            LOG.info("Calling" + url + " to validate token.")
            req = requests.post(url, json=payload)
            result = req.json()

            if result['result'] is False:
                LOG.info("Token not valid anymore.")
                raise PermissionDenied
        else:
            LOG.info("Big Error")
            requests.HTTPError()

        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response
```

I start my django server and did some Post requests (created users via admin, login, etc.), but none of the Logs in the code was displayed in the terminal.

I added it to settings.py in the MIDDLEWARE variable, that django knows I have a custom one.
Although I did all the things that has to be done, there are no logs.

Comment: 1) Did you add this middleware to the `MIDDLEWARE` list in the settings? 2) What is the value of `DEBUG` in your settings?

Comment: 1) yes, it is in MIDDLEWARE and 2) DEBUG=True

Comment: Have you added logging to settings file . Please share the same https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/logging/

Comment: @ku11, were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding logging in the `settings.py`

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'WARNING',
    },
}
```

Full documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/logging/#default-logging-configuration